# Show $\mathbb{Z}G$ is a noetherian ring for finite group $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, finite-groups, modules, noetherian

> Let $G$ be a finite group. Show that $\mathbb{Z}G$ is noetherian as a ring.

It's noetherian as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module (this follows because $\mathbb{Z}$ is noetherian and $\mathbb{Z}G$  isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^{|G|}$ as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module). From here it 'looks' noetherian because (speaking very very loosely) it seems like once you account for the ascending chain condition of $\mathbb{Z}$, you're only going to get finitely many new ideals by introducing multiplication by linear combinations of elements of $G$... (I know... very imprecise... but it's only nebulous intuition at this stage).

The question is from a first course in module theory. Relevant level might be similar to the presentation in Jacobson's Basic Algebra.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @Crostul How do you prove that $\mathbb{Z}G$ is a noetherian ring?

Comment: Any ascending chain of ideals is an ascending chain of $\Bbb{Z}$-submodules, hence it is stationary. Done.

Comment: @Crostul so to check I'm understanding (and to lay it out in more general terms): given any subring $S \leq R$, if $R$ is noetherian when viewed as a $S$-module then it is noetherian when viewed as a ring (i.e. as an $R$-module)?

Comment: Yes, this is always true, and the reason is the same. Any ascending chain of $R$-submodules is an ascending chain of $S$-submodules, hence it is stationary.

Comment: @Crostul thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hint: show that being finitely generated over $\Bbb Z$ implies finitely generated over $\Bbb ZG$.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a Noetherian $Z$-module, consider an ideal of $ZG$, it is a $Z$-submodule of $ZG$, thus it is finitely generated over $Z$, this implies that it is finitely generated ring.

Comment: A "subring"? Did you mean an "ideal"? It is a "finitely generated ring" or "finitely generated ideal"?